# BeautifulSoup - Scraping data through paginated table using Python

Tags: python, pagination, beautifulsoup

I am scraping data through a betting site
(https://www.pointdevente.parionssport.fdj.fr/parisouverts/rugby).

I can scrape a limited number of events on the current page. The issue I am facing is that I am unable to scrape through the rest of data in the table . 
How do I go to the next page or link.

Following is my code:

```
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
import requests
import dryscrape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

dryscrape.start_xvfb()
SessionFDJ = dryscrape.Session()
SessionFDJ.visit('https://pointdevente.parionssport.fdj.fr/parisouverts/rugby/')
ResponseFDJ = SessionFDJ.body()
print(ResponseFDJ)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page use `JavaScript` to get all data and change it. Use `DevTools` in `Chrome/Firefox` to see what files/urls are used by browser and you see

https://www.pointdevente.parionssport.fdj.fr/api/1n2/offre?sport=964500

which gives all data as `JSON`.

It seems this page use `API` so find API documentation and you will no need `BeautifulSoup`

---

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.pointdevente.parionssport.fdj.fr/api/1n2/offre?sport=964500'

r = requests.get(url)

for x in data:
    print(x['label'])
```

result:

```
Biarritz-Perpignan
Kenya-France
Australie-Japon
Etats-Unis-Ecosse
Argentine-Pays de Galles
Angleterre-Samoa
Montauban-Colomiers
Bourgoin-Angoulême
Aurillac-Mt-de-Marsan
Dax-Albi
Vannes-Béziers
Ospreys-Edimbourg
Glasgow-Munster
Sale-Exeter
Bath-Saracens
Pau-Clermont
Zebre-Llanelli
Angleterre-Australie
Connacht-Trévise
Gloucester-Bristol
Leicester-Northampton
Cardiff-Ulster
Grenoble-Montpellier
Lyon-Castres
St.Français-Bayonne
Leinster-Newport
La Rochelle-Racing 92
Toulouse-Brive
Narbonne-Oyonnax
Worcester-Wasps
Newcastle-Harlequins
Toulon-Bordeaux
Fidji-Canada
NlleZélande-Russie
Agen-Carcassonne
AfriqueduSud-Ouganda
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was obviously not doing this the right way. Will explore the JSON library.

Answer (score 0):

This is a client-rendered application, there is no table info in HTML you can get via urllib. All data is retrieved and rendered with Javascript. It's even easier, you don't have to parse HTML.

Here is a link, that has necessary data - https://www.pointdevente.parionssport.fdj.fr/api/1n2/offre?sport=964500

It returns JSON with all events, you can use Python [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) library to parse it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was obviously not doing this the right way. Will explore the JSON library.